# PHP stops at, and shows, a single line of code

Tags: php, sql, apache

Recently I copied a PHP script to use it for another database. After I correctly edited all the words and links, I got an weird error.

```
SELECT naam, aantal, prijs 
FROM boeken, bestelling 
WHERE boeken.Boekcode = bestelling.Boekcode 
AND bestelling.Boekcode IN ('101','102') 
AND bestelnummer = 3;
```

It's not a regular error that say something like

```
Error on line 42
```

Basically what the code does, is that when you order books and filled in a form (Name, last name, email etc) it puts that in a database. And afterwards puts it in a "thankyou.html" page.

Here's part of the code that causes this

```
mysqli_query($con, $query) or die($query . "<br>");
    $bestelnummer = MYSQLI_INSERT_ID($con);

    $object = array_filter($object);
    $objectnaam = join("','",array_keys($object));
    $object = http_build_query($object);
    $object = str_replace('=', ',', $object);
    $object = str_replace('&', "),($bestelnummer,", $object);

    $query = "INSERT INTO bestelling (bestelnummer, Boekcode, aantal) VALUES ($bestelnummer,$object)";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die($query."<br>");

    $aantal = "SELECT naam, aantal, prijs FROM boeken, bestelling WHERE boeken.Boekcode = bestelling.Boekcode AND bestelling.Boekcode IN ('".$objectnaam."') AND bestelnummer = $bestelnummer";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $aantal) or die($aantal . "<br>");

    $res = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
    $prijs = 0;
```

The $object is an array of the books you choose.

I've Google'd for this problem, and yes, I have Apache and everything enabled.

Sorry if I'm unclear, it's been a while, I can answer any questions you might have.

Comment: its `error on line 42`? don't be satisfied with that, use `$con->error` to find out

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. It's been a while. How do I do that?

Comment: instead of `or die(query)` use `die($con->error)` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, I figured out what the error was. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Well you echo out the query if it fails.

```
    $aantal = "SELECT naam, aantal, prijs FROM boeken, bestelling WHERE boeken.Boekcode = bestelling.Boekcode AND bestelling.Boekcode IN ('".$objectnaam."') AND bestelnummer = $bestelnummer";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $aantal) or die($aantal . "<br>");
```

You might want to check the error message that is returned from the database using mysqli_error().

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $aantal) or die(mysqli_error() . "<br>");
```

Comment: I fugured out what was wrong with that. Some words were typed incorrectly. But because of the "or die($query."<br>");" I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

first need to refine

```
$query = "INSERT INTO bestelling (bestelnummer, Boekcode, aantal) VALUES ($bestelnummer,$object)";
```

you are selecting values insertion for 3 columns and passing only two values

For second query try to use **backticks** for tablename and column

Comment: A friend of mine helped me with that. He got that working, so I was convinced it was normal.